# Actualizar datos tabla AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net

Actualicé el modelo de AspNetUser para añadir nuevos campos, lo típico, nombre, apellidos, ect. que por defecto no vienen con el User.

Estoy intentando actualizar dichos datos, una vez que obtengo el Id del Usuario, y como al registrar no se llenan esos campos, pues para poder completarlos.

Bien estoy intentando hacer solo con un campo a ver si soy capaz de que me actualice, no me lanza error pero tampoco me actualiza el campo que viene desde el form.

¿Es el método? Ya probé, con `.SaveChange()` y ese no lo acepta.

```
using EShopOS.Core; 
using EShopOS.DAL; 
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity; 
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework; 
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin; 
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web;    
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace EShopOS.Web.Account {    
public partial class AddContacDateUser : System.Web.UI.Page    {
   
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
   {
      var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
       var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

       txtUserId.Text = user.Id.ToString();
       txtEmail.Text = user.Email;
       txtCity.Text = user.City;
       txtCodPostal.Text = user.PostalCode.ToString();
       txtPostalAddress.Text = user.PostalAddress;
       txtName.Text = user.NameAndSurname;
   }

   protected void Unnamed12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           var manager1 = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
           var currentUser = manager1.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
           
           currentUser.NameAndSurname = txtName.Text;
           manager1.UpdateAsync(currentUser);
           Response.Redirect("home");
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
                error.Text =   ex.ToString();
          
       }

     }
    } 
}
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: A qué te refieres con "ese no lo acepta"?

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por vuestra respuesta. Finalmente encontré la solución, y es que me cargaba la página de nuevo, y claro, encontraba de nuevo vacíos los campos. Hay que usar un `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` quedaría así:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        orderManager = new OrderManager(context);
        shoppingCartManager = new ShoppingCartManager(context);

        var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            txtUserId.Text = user.Id.ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = user.Email;
            txtCity.Text = user.City;
            txtCodPostal.Text = user.PostalCode.ToString();
            txtPostalAddress.Text = user.PostalAddress;
            txtName.Text = user.NameAndSurname;
        }

    }
```